# How can Change CODE imacros to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, console

I want to change tis code from imacros code to .js or .jQ
any one help please

```
FRAME NAME="google_ads_frame3"

EVENT TYPE=CLICK 
SELECTOR="#taw0>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>DIV>A>IMG" BUTTON=0
```

Comment: There is no way to change that menu with JavaScript. No clue what the code snipplet has to do with this question.

Comment: Do u have any methode other not javascripte @epascarello     please i need your help sir :'(

Comment: this code jut for accept my question in stackoverflow

Comment: **There is no way to change that menu with JavaScript** in the console.

Comment: thanks @epascarello for answer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll get the best results here by posting your attempt at solving the problem and seeking feedback.  You'll get downvotes if you just ask for a solution without an attempt.

Answer (score -1):

```
var macro;

macro ='CODE:';
macro +='FRAME NAME="google_ads_frame3"'+'\n';
macro +='EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#taw0>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>DIV>A>IMG" BUTTON=0'+'\n';

iimPlay(macro);
```